# Should I multithread my Node JS web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker

I have a simple Node.JS HTTPS web server using socket.io. Users can send to the server lots of different information. In a few seconds, you may have the web server receive multiple one line objects to the web server from one user (i.e. `{ code: '124' }`, but there may be multiple users doing this at once. Then the web server returns information to all users in that socket.io room.

As this information comes in, the web server intermittently saves this data to a simple MySQL database although I am limiting saves so that there aren't multiple small MySQL writes per second or anything like that.

My thought process is that as more users log onto and connect to the web server, the code may become blocked as Node.JS is single threaded, and this may cause a lag in information getting back to the users in real time, or it may cause problems with the latest data being saved to the database. I was thinking of doing something like this so that the database updates is handled by a separate web worker -

```
socket.on('data', function(msg) {
    try {
        const newWorker = new Worker('./src/worker.js');

        newWorker.on('message', function(result) { 
            io.to(`${socketID}`).emit('newData', result);
        });

        newWorker.on('error', (err) => {
            io.to(`${socketID}`).emit('newData', { error: err });
            console.dir(err);
        });

        newWorker.postMessage(msg);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e); 
        io.to(`${socketID}`).emit('criticalError', "We ran into an error - try refreshing");        

    }
});
```

I know however, that async processes can be run on multiple threads in the background of Node.JS and Node.JS is generally quite performant.

**My question is,** given that there may be multiple database writes happening simultaneously, as well as multiple pieces of information coming in, which then need to be sent back to users in any given second, **does it make sense for me to use web workers to make this kind of process mulithreaded**? Or is Node.JS capable enough to handle all of this in the background on multiple threads without me needing to worry?

Comment: I think you'll not gain much from multi-thread, and if you want to try out, you should make sure you config your database correctly to access it multi-threaded.

Comment: Have you considered *message queue* instead? Have a look at RabbitMQ or Amazon SQS.

Comment: I haven't, I will check out those solutions though.